# How to measure the duration time of sending and receiving data separetly in http request

Tags: java, http

I need to measure the following time separately during HTTP request using Java:

1. Connection time
2. Sending request time
3. Receiving response time

Currently I can only measure the connection time and together request and response time:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        Instant time1 = Instant.now();
        connection.connect();
        Instant time2 = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
        Instant time3 = Instant.now();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        stream.readAllBytes();
        Instant time4 = Instant.now();

        System.out.printf("Connection: %d ms\n", Duration.between(time1, time2).toMillis());
        System.out.printf("Request/Receive Headers : %d ms\n", Duration.between(time2, time3).toMillis());
        System.out.printf("Receive Body : %d ms\n", Duration.between(time3, time4).toMillis());
```

// Output:

- Connection: 296 ms
- Request/Receive Headers : 156 ms
- Receive Body : 437 ms

**How to measure "Request" time separately?**

Comment: I don't think your way of measuring the Response time is correct. You can get the response code very fast, but still have to wait quite a long time before receiving the last byte of the file.

Comment: Thank you @Benoit, I updated my code